# In Node.js, how to update different components of a page in different frequency?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

I'm trying to build a real time webpage to show some real time statistics. This webpage has 12 components. I'm using Ajax in SetTimeout to update each component. Since I'd like to update each component in different frequency, I write a setTimeout function for each component and gives each component a link (defined in "main.js"). Looks like:

```
(function poll() {
 setTimeout(function() {
  $.ajax({

    url: url1,
    type: 'GET',
    success : function(info){
      var object = document.getElementById("1");
      object.textContent = info;

    }, complete: poll });
  }, 5000);
})();

   ...
   ...

(function poll() {
 setTimeout(function() {
  $.ajax({

    url: url12,
    type: 'GET',
    success : function(info){
      var object = document.getElementById("12");
      object.textContent = info;

    }, complete: poll });
  }, 10000);
})();
```

And in my "server.js", I hope to connect to database only once and then render different components. The configuration of the database will rely on the link so I organize the app like this:

```
app.get('/:A/:B', function(req,res){

    var A= req.params.A;
    var B = req.params.B;
    var config = something relies on A and B

    var client = new pg.Client(config);

    client.connect(function(err){
      if (err) {
       console.log("Error occurred when try to connect the database",err);
    }
      else {
       res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/main.html');

       app.get('/main.js', function(req,res){
         res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/main.js');
       });

       app.get('/url1',function(req,res) {
         //query database and send the data url1 needs
       });

       ...
       ...
       app.get('/url12',function(req,res) {
         //query database and send the data url12 needs
       });


    })
```

I want to ask if writing "app.get()" within "app.get()" like the code above is good practice. If not, how can I keep a global connection to the database and use it for different components? Also, is there any improvement I can make to this web app? I'm quite new to Node.js

Comment: use websocket instead of AJAX for more performance

Comment: You can't put `app.get()` inside of another `app.get()`.  These handlers are installed on your server for all users so this will never be a desired behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to do this with callbacks instead of promises, this is how I would do it on Server side.

first, I would use your endpoint to get the client, but would put it in a module internal variable, and still send a response if I failed to connect to DB.

```
var db=null;
app.get('/:A/:B', function(req,res){

var A= req.params.A;
var B = req.params.B;
var config = something relies on A and B

var client = new pg.Client(config);

client.connect(function(err){
  if (err) {
   console.log("Error occurred when try to connect the database",err);
   res.status(503).send("Error connecting to database);
  }
  else {
   db = client;
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/main.html');
  }
}
}
```

Then, I would write a function that would reuse that DB if it exists:

```
function usingDatabase(req,res,next){
    if(db) {
       req.db=db;
       next();
    }
    else {
       res.status(400).send("Bad request. open the DB first by calling /:A/:B");
    }
}
```

finally I'd use it like this:
    app.get('/main.js', function(req,res){
         res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/main.js');
       });

```
   app.get('/url1',usingDatabase, function(req,res) {
     // db is in req.db;
     //query database and send the data url1 needs
   });

   ...
   ...
   app.get('/url12',usingDatabase,function(req,res) {
     // db is in req.db;
     //query database and send the data url12 needs
   });
```

Comment: Thank you! This structure looks much cleaner and works perfectly :)